# Python3 How to retrieve list from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

I want to create a user-defined input that retrieves the list within the list of stk_pairs.

For example, when the input prompts the user to select which pair they want, e.g. 1, it means that it will retrieve the second element of the stk_pairs list; in this case is [ 'C', 'D']

```
stk_pairs = [['A, B'],
              ['C', 'D'],
              ['E', 'F']]

print('1st pair is A and B; indicated as 0')
print('2nd pair is C and D; indicated as 1')
print('3rd pair is E and F; indicated as 2')

get_stk_pairs = input('choose which pair to compare: ')
answer = stk_pairs[get_stk_pairs]
print(answer)
```

However, I get this error:

Output

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the user input to `int` (as by default it is of type`str`) so that can be used as an index in retrieving the elements from the list:

```
get_stk_pairs = int(input('choose which pair to compare: '))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that the input value will be an `int` type to be accepted as the index of your list while by default the input is a `str`. So your code should be changed to this:

```
get_stk_pairs = int(input('choose which pair to compare: '))
```